# Why Django update page and log out didn't work?

Tags: django, django-views

[This is dashboard page with django login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VXA0.png)

[This is analyse page after i login but the user didn#t show  up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdbL2.png)

I click the analyse page when i am anonumoususer, the user didn't change after i login

I don't get the reason why i am logged in but the user did not show up.

Besides when i click logout it doesn't work either.Below is my logout code. I really appreciate it if anyone could help me!!

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
import hashlib
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,get_user_model,login,logout,get_user
from .forms import UserLoginForm,UserRegisterForm
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template,Context
from .decorators import unauthenticated_user,allowed_users, admin_only
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@csrf_exempt
@unauthenticated_user
def login_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    form =UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        login(request,user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        else:
            return redirect('/home')
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request,'users/login.html',context)


def index(request):
    return render(request,'users/home.html')

@csrf_exempt
def register_view(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    register_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if register_form.is_valid():
        user = register_form.save(commit=False)
        password = register_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username,password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return redirect('/userlist')
    context = {
        'form': register_form,
    }

    return render(request,'register.html',context)

def logout_view(request):
    user = get_user(request)

    logout(request)
    request.session.flush()
    print('you are log out from cms!')
    request.user = AnonymousUser
    return render(request,'logout.html')

def userlist(request):
    User = get_user_model()
    result = User.objects.all()
    #template = Template('userlist.html')
    #html = template.render(Context({'content': result}))
    return render(request,'userlist.html',{'content':result})

def adduser(request):
    return render(request,'todo.html')


@login_required(login_url='accounts/login/')
def notpermitted(request):
    return render(request,'NotPermitted.html')
```

This is the side bar in template. The sidebar will change based on user roll.

```
{% load static %}
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="/home">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{% static 'img/cms.png'%}" alt="" width="72" height="57">
                </div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/dashboard">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Function
            </div>

            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            {% if request.user.is_staff %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
                    <span>Dataset</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Dataset:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/adddata">Add Dataset</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/datasetlist">Datasets</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
                
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>historical Data</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Dataset:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/upload">upload</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/home">Rest</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endif %}

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="/processed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>ProcessedData</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Dataset:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/processed">list</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/processed/opc">opc</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/processed/mqtt">mqtt</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>



            <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="/analyse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
                        <span>Analyse</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities"
                    data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Methode:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/analyse/fft">Fast Fourier Methode</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/analyse/limit_monitoring">Limit Monitoring</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">


            {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Usermanagement
            </div>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Users</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">User:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/userlist">List</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="/adduser">add User</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

This is topbar! the current user will be listed here.
``

```
                <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>

                <!-- Topbar Search -->
                <form
                    class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-3 my-2 my-md-0 mw-100 navbar-search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..."
                            aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                    <!-- Nav Item - Search Dropdown (Visible Only XS) -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow d-sm-none">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="searchDropdown" role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Dropdown - Messages -->
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right p-3 shadow animated--grow-in"
                            aria-labelledby="searchDropdown">
                            <form class="form-inline mr-auto w-100 navbar-search">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small"
                                        placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search"
                                        aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                                            <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Nav Item - Alerts -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="/accounts/login/" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">Login</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/accounts/logout/" class="nav-link link-dark px-2">Logout</a></li>
                    </li>

                    <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

                    <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button"
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Hello, {{ request.user }}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

````
I use request.user to decide the user roll. it seems to be that the page is stored in the browser when i first load this page. So when i update the page after i login in, the page i loaded before didn't change the user in sidebar and topbar. i disabled cookies and cache in my browser but it still doesn't work, hope anyone hat a answer!

Comment: Can you share the template as well?

Comment: yeah sure, i share the sidebar and topbar, the user should be showed here,but it just didn't. When i first load the page ,the user is stored and when i click logout or login with anaother user, the listed user stays unchanged.